# Select closest date in sequence in two time series tables and join them

Tags: postgresql

For an entire audit trail, I'm trying to select the closest records to each date (on or before) in a sequence of weekly dates. I need to do this on two tables, and join the results for each date in the sequence

I was able to do this in python, but it was so incredibly slow, so I'm trying to do it directly in postgres, but I'm very unfamiliar with looping/functions etc. I know I'll generate a sequence of dates doing something like this:

```sql
SELECT d::date
FROM generate_series(TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2019-06-03' -- START DATE
,TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2019-10-17' -- END DATE
,'7 day') AS gs(d);
```

Here is what the starting data will look like

Table 1:

```
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+
| idA    | history_date | status | idB |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+
| 123456 | 2019-09-15   | 1      | 1   |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+
| 123456 | 2019-09-17   | 2      | 1   |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+
| 654321 | 2019-09-01   | 3      | 5   |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+
| 654321 | 2019-09-25   | 5      | 5   |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+
```

Table 2:

```
+-----+--------------+--------+
| idB | history_date | active |
+-----+--------------+--------+
| 1   | 2019-08-01   | true   |
+-----+--------------+--------+
| 1   | 2019-09-03   | false  |
+-----+--------------+--------+
| 5   | 2019-09-01   | true   |
+-----+--------------+--------+
| 5   | 2019-09-25   | false  |
+-----+--------------+--------+
```

For example, I need to select the closest records on or before 2019-09-16 and 2019-09-23.

For ex idA=123456 for seq_date=2019-09-16, I would take the 2019-09-15 record

For ex idB=1 for seq_date=2019-09-16, I would take the 2019-09-03 record.

I would then join these two records to get the full record for 2019-09-16 idA

For table 1, the result of the first step would be:

```
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+------------+
| idA    | history_date | status | idB | seq_date   |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+------------+
| 123456 | 2019-09-15   | 1      | 1   | 2019-09-16 |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+------------+
| 123456 | 2019-09-17   | 2      | 1   | 2019-09-23 |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+------------+
| 654321 | 2019-09-01   | 3      | 5   | 2019-09-16 |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+------------+
| 654321 | 2019-09-01   | 3      | 5   | 2019-09-23 |
+--------+--------------+--------+-----+------------+
```

for table 2, the result of the first step would be:

```
+-----+--------------+--------+------------+
| idB | history_date | active | seq_date   |
+-----+--------------+--------+------------+
| 1   | 2019-09-03   | false  | 2019-09-16 |
+-----+--------------+--------+------------+
| 1   | 2019-09-03   | false  | 2019-09-23 |
+-----+--------------+--------+------------+
| 5   | 2019-09-01   | true   | 2019-09-16 |
+-----+--------------+--------+------------+
| 5   | 2019-09-01   | true   | 2019-09-23 |
+-----+--------------+--------+------------+
```

My expected result is this: (Joined on seq_date)

```
+--------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
| idA    | seq_date   | status | idB | active |
+--------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
| 123456 | 2019-09-16 | 1      | 1   | false  |
+--------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
| 123456 | 2019-09-23 | 2      | 1   | false  |
+--------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
| 654321 | 2019-09-16 | 3      | 5   | true   |
+--------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
| 654321 | 2019-09-23 | 3      | 5   | true   |
+--------+------------+--------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: How do you get from `2019-09-03` to `2019-09-16` for `idA = 654321`? For me, the algorithm needs more description.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added an intermediary step for each table if that helps